# After Python to C conversion via Cython, getting undefined symbol _Py_CheckRecursionLimit

Tags: python, numpy, cython

with the goal of executing a block of code, some involving Python scripts, in Android OS, I converted a Python script to C via Cython as follows. setup.py has      this:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Compiler import Options

Options.embed = "main"

setup(
 ext_modules = cythonize("make_region.pyx")
)
```

Next, do the conversion to C with:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

which generates make_region.c (note: Python version is 3.10.0)
Then compile make_region.c with:

```
 gcc  make_region.c -o make_region.exe -I/home/me/PYTHON-3.10.0/include/python3.10 -L/home/me/PYTHON-3.10.0/lib -lpython3.10 -ldl -lm -lutil -lpthread
```

This yielded an initial error of:
No module named numpy.core._multiarray_umath.  Many posts suggested fixing this via:

```
 pip install numpy --upgrade
```

However, this did not solve my problem, so circumvented this error, by doing:

```
 ln -s _multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _multiarray_umath.so
```

in numpy/core (note: I had created a local copy of numpy in my working directory).  A new attempt at compiling make_region.c is yielding:

```
 numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.so: undefined symbol: _Py_CheckRecursionLimit
```

Indeed, this symbol is not defined in this shared object library or any *.so in numpy/core.  Some searching turned up, at https://bugs.python.org/issue41834, there was a recommendation to remove the _Py_CheckRecursionLimit symbol as of Python version 3.9.  However, I, so far, don't see anything on this issue in regards to numpy.   Any suggestions/ideas anyone may have on this issue are most welcome.

Comment: `_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` that file is _only for use with Python 3.7_. it will not and should not be found by Python 3.10. you should not attempt to circumvent this. You've managed to mix up multiple installs of Python somehow and this is what you should be fixing

Comment: David - greatly appreciate you steering me in the correct direction! Changed the C compile to use python 3.7m headers and lib as follows:gcc  make_region.c -o make_region.exe -I/usr/include/python3.7m -L/usr/lib/python3.7/config3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.7m -ldl -lm -lutil -lpthread.  Can now generate and run the make_region.exe.  Now onto the simple matter of cross-compiling Python for use on Android :>